# Silverlight DataGrid: changing the color of certain cells

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

When I bind my datasource to my grid

```
 dataGrid.DataContext = myObservableCollection;
```

.. and when a value of a cell is for example >100 how can I have the cell pulsate on and off in a different color?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

To check if the value of the cell is over 100 you can use a [ValidationRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule.aspx).

[Here](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2009/11/06/Validation-in-a-WPF-DataGrid.aspx) is an example of using a custom rule and adding a red border around the cell in error. From there you should be able to extend the example from a red border to an animation (achieving the color pulsating).

I've omitted a code sample as the mini tutorial has a well illustrated solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi Ragepotato, the first link doesn't show how to apply the validation rule to a column in a DataGrid. It just shows how to define a validation rule and i can't find how to apply it? And the second link uses the DataGrid from the Silverlight toolkit which i am not using and i can't get the code to work with a regular dataGrid

Comment: Sorry, I thought the lessons/patterns would be clear and allow you to apply them in other places.